# BootStrap3のテーマを使うには？

Tags: java, html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, seaser2

初質問です！

現在Java、Seasar2(SAStrats/S2JDBC)、JSP、PostgreSQLで
DBを使ったWebアプリケーションを作っています。

そこで質問なのですが、
結論から言うと

**BootStrap3のテーマを今作っているアプリケーションに反映するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？**

ざっくりしすぎているので説明すると
現在Bootstrap CDNを使ってBootstrap3をJSPに反映させ、ボタンやフォームなどを鮮やかなデザインにすることはできています。

次は画面全体的に鮮やかなデザインにしたく、Bootstrap3のテーマの使用を考えています。

しかし、調べても今の自分の環境に反映させる方法が見つかりません。

**方法そのもの、あるいは関連サイトなど教えて頂ける方がいればよろしくお願いします。**

---

これ(現状)を
[image: 現状]
↓
こんな感じにしたい。こういうのを反映させたいです。
[image]
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

適用したいBootstrap3のデザインのCSSやJavaScript、画像ファイルなどを入手してデザインが公開されているサイトの手順にあわせたディレクトリやファイルを配置するか、それらのソースを参照するURLを修正するかのどちらかになります。
この手順はBootstrap3のデザインを適用されたときと全く同じです。

適用のさせ方がわからないのか、入手の方法がわからないのか、そもそも何らかのエラーが出ていて動かないのかわかりませんのでこれ以上明確な回答はできかねます。

Comment: A-pzさん
ご返答ありがとうございます。
単純に適用のさせ方がわからないという質問でした。無料テンプレートのダウンロードの仕方はある程度想像ができていたので。言葉足らずだったかもしれません。ただほんとに具体的な部分に行き着く前のところで引っかかっていたので、Bootstrap3のデザインを適用されたときと同じという回答で一枚壁を破ることができました。ありがとうございます。

追加質問をしたいのですが、少し長ったらしくなりそうで投稿が見にくくなりそうなので新たにスレを立てます。
「BootStrap3のテーマを使うには？（2）」
とかにします。
よかったら見て下さい。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @k499778 単に「(2)」を付けるだけですとこの質問との区別が付きませんから、（多少長くなっても）もう少し具体的なタイトルを考えていただけないでしょうか。質問内容がはっきりしているのであれば、それを要約するといいかもしれません。

Comment: unaristさん
ご返答ありがとうございます。
・結論の部分は変わらない
・前の投稿と関連しているとわかりやすい
といったメリットが感じられたのでそうしようかとも思いましたが、unaristさんの意見もその通りだと思います。

ただ新しいスレを立てようかと思ったのですが、
自力で解決できたのでここに結論を載せたいと思います。
unaristさん、アドバイス感謝しています。

Answer (score 0):

**解決しました！！**

投稿したときより進捗は進んでいて
ダウンロードしたテーマのテンプレートをうまくJSPに反映させることができない。
という所で引っかかっていました。

しかし、次のような階層構造にするとJSPにimgファイルやcssファイルなどを読み込ませることができ、反映させることができました。

↓before
[image]

↓after
[image]

読み込めなかったのは
**J2EEの「ブラウザからはWEB-INF以下が直接参照できない」という仕様**
によるものでした。

なので**WEB-INFより上の階層にcssファイルなどを置く**と読み込ませることができたという訳です。

あとはテンプレをダウンロードしたときのindex.htmlの書き方をjspに写すだけです。
[image]

そうすると自分のアプリにテンプレートを反映させることができました。
[image]

あとはこれをログイン画面ぽく変えたいと思います。
ご清聴ありがとうございました。